# Unexpected end of JSON input - ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

i can't figure out why the ajax function is failed - still it deletes proper item from DB

myquery (class Book)

```
 static public function deleteFromDB(mysqli $conn, $id) {
        if (!is_null($id)) {
            $result = $conn->query('DELETE FROM books WHERE id=' . intval ($id));
        }

    }
```

server method

```
else if ('DELETE' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $data);

    $id = $data['id'];

    Book::deleteFromDB($conn, $id);
}
```

my ajax function:

```
$('#bookList').on('click', '.deleteButton', function () {
       // event.preventDefault();
        var deleteButton = $(this);
        //console.log(deleteButton);
        //console.log(deleteButton.attr('data-id'));
        var bookId = deleteButton.attr('data-id');
        //console.log(bookId);


        $.ajax({
            url: 'api/books.php',
            type: 'DELETE',
            data: "id=" + bookId,
            dataType: 'json'

        }).done(function (result) {
            console.log('Successfully deleted book of id:' + bookId);
        }).fail(function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
            console.log('Book delete error ' + errorThrown);
        });
    });
```

id deletes the item from DB but still ajax function is failed

Comment: can you just log result in string format using JSON.stringify(result)

Comment: What does 'fail' mean? What exactly is your error?

Comment: Its the output from .fail: Book delete error SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: what do u mean by that @axcl? to put result in .done as JSON.stringify? it doesnt do anything from .done, it just goes to .fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by adding:

```
header('Location: http://localhost/Books/index.php');
```

after `Book::deleteFromDB($conn, $id);`

seems like ajax was trying to delete the same item over and over again and couldnt find id. Now it works, still cant understand why:P

Answer (score 0):

You don't return anything from server.

```
 static public function deleteFromDB(mysqli $conn, $id) {
        if (!is_null($id)) {
            return $conn->query('DELETE FROM books WHERE id=' . intval ($id));
        }

    }
```

---

```
else if ('DELETE' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $data);

    $id = $data['id'];

    return Book::deleteFromDB($conn, $id);
}
```

Comment: Ok. Try to delete dataType: 'json' from ajax properties